# Why does Google Reader only update our site's RSS feed once every 4-5 days?

Tags: google, rss

We have a website with a RSS feed. When I use Google Reader to subscribe to the feed, it is only updated once in a while - something like every 4-5 days. In Google Reader the latest 2 or 3 posts appear at the same time.

I have setup an quick test script that downloads the RSS feed every hour, so that I could monitor, that the feed is updated as expected. And everything looks good, when I just download the feed.

I'm beginning to believe that the cause for this behavior in Google Reader is to do with Googles RSS crawler, feedfetcher. When I look at Date Received and Date Published - Google Reader differentiate between Date Received and Date Published - Date Received is the same for the 2 or 3 posts, and Date Published matchtes the pubDate in the feed.

This leads me to believe that Google's RSS crawler, feedfecther, doesn't crawl the RSS feed more that something like every 4-5 days.

What are your experiences with Google feedfetcher? Is it expected to have this kind of latency?

(I haven't looked at the server logs yet, but that would be a logically next step.)

Comment: Do you have a [ttl](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#element-channel-ttl) set in the feed?  I can't confirm whether or not Google pays any attention to it, a quick search produced conflicting reports, but it may be worth investigating.

Comment: How does it work if you ping? http://pingomatic.com/ My experience is that GR updates immediately after a post in my unknown Wordpress blog.

Comment: Try adding your feed to feedburner.google.com and ensure your publishing system/CMS is pinging services like Pingomatic

Comment: @robertc No TTL defined anywhere.

Comment: @Osvaldo I will look at Pingomatic - thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Mike Hudson I have considered using Feedburner. But thanks for suggesting!

Comment: Have you validated your feed, for example with http://validator.w3.org/feed/ ?

Comment: @paulmorriss Actually I haven't. Will get right on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After monitoring Google Reader for a couple of weeks, it seems that Google's feedfetcher bot now visits the RSS feed on a regular schedule. The conclusion therefore is that there are some degree of latency between the first subscription to a RSS feed from a Google service till the RSS feed are regularly indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Feeds are checked "[about once an hour](http://support.google.com/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&lev=answer&cbid=qybltj9ifxum&answer=70642&src=cb)" but that schedule "may" be reduced if there aren't many subscribers. (Note the usual vagueness you get from Google about pretty much everything. This was one of the reasons I stopped using Reader for almost all feed reading myself; there's no real way of knowing unless you actually publish the feed yourself and check.)
I've never encountered a lag as bad as you're describing, though.